# How can I restore my Outlook 2010 setup?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

My old C drive which ran XP is now a storage drive in my new Win7 machine.

I'm using the same edition of Office as I previously was and have already located and imported my email messages from the pst file.  What I don't see are my old account settings.

How can I restore those settings, given that my original drive is still intact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook doesn't have a way to import or export user settings/preferences, BUT in [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/where-does-microsoft-outlook-2010-save-my-information-and-configurations-HP010354943.aspx) Microsoft lists file locations where some of the personalization settings are stored.

You can try to move these files from the old hard drive to the new drive. Before doing so, I would suggest renaming the existing Outlook file so if copying the file doesn't work, you can restore the file that does.

Comment: I had read that article, but since it specifically did not mention the pop3 account settings I came here to find a different approach.

Comment: It doesn't exclude POP3. Did you try any of the suggested files?

Comment: I must be missing it, there are 2 references to POP3 - one about autocomplete and the other about rules ... both references are associated to pop3 accounts, but are not the settings for the pop3 itself.  I'm not using exchange so several of the other files aren't relevant and the bulk of the remainder are antiquated files not created/supported by 2010 but are listed in case you're upgrading from an older edition.

Comment: Sorry. Thought it would help. I think I misunderstood exactly what you are looking to do.